# NullPointerException on service spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I'm new to Spring so I'm just trying to understand how it works. I've developed a simple servletprojectusing spring to manage hibernate framework.

I have a service

```
@Service("service")
@Transactional
public class CdServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateUtility hibernateutility;

    public int saveCd(CD cd) {
        return hibernateutility.saveCd(cd);
    }

    public List getCd(String searchedCd) {
        return hibernateutility.getCd(searchedCd);
    }

    public List getAllCd() {
        return hibernateutility.getAllCd();
    }

    public void deleteCd(int id) {
        hibernateutility.deleteCd(id);
    }

    public User getUser(String username, String password) {
        return hibernateutility.getUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

And then I use it in the servlet

```
context.scan("it.project");
    context.refresh();
   CdServiceImpl service = (CdServiceImpl) context.getBean("service"); 
    context.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
    context.refresh();
```

1) It works but I have two question. It is the right way to work?
2) I've tried to set a field in the servlet like:

```
@Autowired
    private CdServiceImpl service
```

and then I remove the *context.scan* ecc part and it gave me nullpointerexception. Why?

Doing that I also defined a new bean

```
@Bean
    public CdServiceImpl getCdServiceImpl() {
        return new CdServiceImpl();
    }
```

Why it doesn't work? I know that maybe this is a noob question but I'm tryingto figure out how spring works

Comment: context scan is required if you have not declared your beans in xml file explicitly because using this component scan Spring will create Singleton bean and that's why you don't need to initialize it using new keyword but if you are not scanning and you have not provided definition in Spring file then you have to use new keyword to initialize it.

Comment: (I'm using annotations) In my configuration file I defined a bean! See the last lines of my question

Comment: 1. No it isn't. 2. Your servlet isn't managed by spring so it cannot inject dependencies.

Comment: And what is the right wayto do that? What can I do to managed the servlet with spring?

Comment: You don't need to. You can do a lookup but the way you are doing a lookup is the wrong way. Use a `ContextLoaderListener` to load your root application context, then use `WebApplicationContextUtils` in your servlets `init` method to get the `ApplicationContext`, grap the depenency and set it into an instance field. You should create and refresh things like you do.

Comment: Could u explain how to do that? I havetocreate a object "contextloaderlistener"?

Answer (score 0):

Basically as soon as you start doing things like `new **ApplicationContext` you need to scratch your head, take 2 steps away from the keyboard and think if you really want to do this. In 99% of the cases this isn't what you want or at least should do.

Instead have the `ContextLoaderListener` load your configuration. Assuming you don't have a `web.xml` use the the `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` base class.

```
public ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractContextLoaderInitializer {


    protected WebApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
    }

}
```

**Note:** As this is for bootstrapping your application you need to create the the context. You could also use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` which eliminates this need, but also creates a `DispatcherServlet` which you don't need.

Now that your configuration is automatically loaded you can use the `WebApplicationContextUtils` to get the context to do the lookup. Do this in the `init` method of your servlet.

```
public class YourServlet extends GenericServlet {

    private CdServiceImpl service;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        service = ctx.getBean(CdServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Now you initialize the bean once and don't need to handle anything anymore. You could also use `@Autowired` and manuallly have it injected.

```
public class YourServlet extends GenericServlet {

    @Autowired
    private CdServiceImpl service;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the first class, the ones which load my configuration where I have to put it? I have to call "createApplicationContext()"somewhere? (sorry spring it'sa new world for me)

Comment: No you don't... The servlet container will call it... Assuming you are using a servlet 3.0 container and you have no `web.xml` or a servlet 3.0 `web.xml`.